# "For what do you go to school?" or "What do you go to school for?"

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

What is the difference in the following two sentences?

- For what do you go to school?
- What do you go to school for?

Comment: The difference is the placing of the preposition! (PS they both require a question mark.)

Comment: Actually I was given the above two sentence to choose the correct one, but I could not find any differences. But according to my book correct answer is the second one.

Comment: The first is correct but formal, and until recently strict grammarians would have called the second a mistake, because the preposition is at the end. Maybe your book is poor quality, or you need to ask your teacher for an explanation.

Comment: I have never heard the first sentence actually used, but it is supposedly correct.